# Next.js/TypeScript: how to add nextPage type to class components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I like to work with `es6 classes` and I'm trying to get proper typings for my next.js project based on typescript.

How do you implement `NextPage` type in a class component?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";

export class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Index</div>;
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: You can't, and there's no need to - what you have is perfectly fine. `NextPage` refers to a type, it can't be used to extend from in a class component. See what the official docs recommend: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#typescript.